# Do we support [language-support]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have a [language-support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/language-support) tag which has the following guidance:

> Questions related to the language support provided by Ubuntu.

We also have a [language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/language) tag  which has the following guidance:

> Questions that relate to the use of different languages in Ubuntu

It is obvious that the tags are similar in scope, identical I might say.

I think that we don't need both and I suggest that we make the [language-support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/language-support) tag a synonym of [language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/language).

Comment: I'd prefer the other way - `language` as a synonym, as `language-support` seems to be clearer in the intent just from the name of the tag.

Comment: @muru Sure, that could work too. I have no objection.

Comment: A quick browse through suggests that there's no difference between how these tags are being used and we can painlessly synonymise them

Comment: I would certainly support a merge...

Comment: 7 days for comment I guess before making the change?

Comment: @andrew.46 I don't see this post getting any more feedback, nor is someone against acting on the tags. So I guess we can go forward with muru's suggestion (which is logical and has the same number of upvotes as this post) and make the `language` tag a synonym of `language-support`.

Comment: Or merge, I don't see an issue with that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small community consensus but nevertheless a consensus. So:

1. I have merged [language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/language) into [language-support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/language-support)
2. *Subsequently* I have created [language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/language) as a synonym for [language-support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/language-support)

Perhaps a little backwards but it is all working well enough...